# Name for a "non-injective" functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be two categories. Let $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor such that, for two non-isomorphic objects $x,y \in \mathcal{C}$ we have
$$
F(x) \simeq F(y).
$$
What do we call this property of $F$? The term "non-injective" is a bad idea for many reasons. This is somewhat different from non-faithfullness and non-conservative.

Comment: You mean C & D are categories, right?

Comment: It's fixed, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353164/functors-reflecting-isomorphism-relations

Comment: I think if F has the “injectivity” property, we say F reflects isomorphisms. So the negation would be something like “non-isomorphism-reflecting”.

Comment: @Alex This is not quite true. It reflects isomorphism relations. See also my answer in the linked (actually, duplicate) thread.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I see, thank you. I had also forgotten the word “conservative”. Do you know any interesting examples of functors that reflect isomorphism relations but are not conservative?

Comment: @AlexMine Yes. Think about one-object categories. And to make it a bit more interesting, $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched ones (aka rings). In this sense, $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is not conservative.